# how to get response status in mock response using jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript2.0

How to get response status and message in without a return function using jest.

**file.test.ts**

```
function data(response:Response){
response.send("hai").status(200)
}
```

I nned how to test this function and check the response result using jest

Comment: Hi @hari, what do you mean with _without return a function using jest_?

Comment: Unit test or integration test, which one do you need?

Comment: integration test

Comment: @hariprasanth Which integration test library do you use?